# How to keep Skype signed in

Tags: skype

Skype keeps logging me out, every time I turn my computer off.

I don't want Skype to open automatically when starting the PC, but I would like to be able to launch Skype without having to sign in every time.

It does not seem possible to set this in the profile settings, as suggested in many forums online.

So, for now I had to insert username and password every time I open Skype.

How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

- Open Skype and sign in
- Click on profile photo > Settings
- Activate settings "On close, keep Skype running" (see image below)
- Close settings
- Close Skype (will stay open in the background)
- Show hidden icons (bottom right corner on Windows 10)
- Right click on Skype icon & quit
- You'll be asked if you "want the keep Skype signed in on this device" > click yes

This should solve the problem

[See settings screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAJGv.png)